# Error with for loop and/or function

Tags: c, function, for-loop

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define numlines 2201
#define linelen 99 


typedef struct 
{ 
    char class[99]; 
    char age[99];
    char gender[99]; 
    char survived[99]; 
} Passenger; 


int cmpStruct(Passenger pa, Passenger Query);

Passenger lineToStruct(char line[]); 

Passenger queryToStruct(char line[]);

int findMyChar(char str[], int size, int start, char ch);

int Computation(Passenger Query, Passenger allPassengers[]);




int main(void) 
{

    FILE *fp;   
    fp = fopen("Titanic.txt", "r");  
    if (fp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error opening file %s, \n", "Titanic.txt");
        return -1; 
    }




    Passenger allPassengers[numlines];
    int n = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        char line[numlines];
        if (fgets(line, linelen, fp) == NULL) 
        { 
            break;
        }

        allPassengers[n] = lineToStruct(line);
        n++;    
    }


    fclose(fp);


    Passenger Query;

    char query[99];

    while (1)
    { 
        printf("\nType 1 for query, or 0 to quit: "); 

            int begin; 

        scanf("%d",&begin);

        if (begin == 0) 
        {         
            printf("Bye Bye!\n\n"); 
            return 0; 
        } 

        while(1)
        {
            printf("Type in the query that you want to know");
            printf(" sample query is: class=first,age=adult,gender=male \n");
            scanf("%s", &query);  
            break;
        }

        int iteration1;
        int iteration2;
        int iteration3; 

        if(query == "all")
        {
            for(iteration1=1; iteration1<=4;iteration1++)
            {

                if(iteration1==1)
                {
                    strcpy(Query.class, "first");
                }
                if(iteration1==2)
                {
                    strcpy(Query.class, "second");
                }
                if(iteration1==3)
                {
                    strcpy(Query.class, "third");
                }
                if(iteration1==4)
                {
                    strcpy(Query.class, "crew");
                }

                for(iteration2=1; iteration2<=2;iteration2++)
                {
                    if(iteration2==1)
                    {
                        strcpy(Query.age, "adult");
                    }
                    if(iteration2==2)
                    {
                        strcpy(Query.age, "child");

                    }

                    for(iteration3=1; iteration3<=2;iteration3++)
                    {
                        if(iteration3==1)
                        {
                            strcpy(Query.gender, "male");
                        }   
                        if(iteration3==2)
                        {
                            strcpy(Query.gender, "female");

                        }

                        Computation(Query, allPassengers);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Query = queryToStruct(query); 

            float totalPassengers = 0; 
            float survived = 0;        
            float percentage;
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<numlines;i++)
            { 

                if (cmpStruct(allPassengers[i],Query)==0)
                { 

                    totalPassengers++; 

                    if (strcmp(allPassengers[i].survived,"yes")==0)
                    {  
                        survived++; 
                        if (cmpStruct(allPassengers[i],Query)==1)
                        {
                            printf("error");
                            break;
                        }
                    } 

                } 

            }


            percentage = survived/totalPassengers*100; 
            printf("\nResults:\n"); 
            printf("\nClass = %s\nAge = %s\nGender = %s\n\n",Query.class,Query.age,Query.gender); 


            if (totalPassengers == 0)
            { 
                printf("There was an error within the query\n"); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                printf("%.0f passengers are in the query (of 2201), %.0f of them survived\n",totalPassengers,survived); 
            } 

            if (totalPassengers != 0)
            { 
                printf("Chance of survival is %.1f%c\n",percentage,'%');
            } 
        } 
    }
}



int findMyChar(char str[], int size, int start,  char ch)
{

    int i; 
    for(i=start;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==ch)
        { 
            return i; 
        } 
    } 
    return -1;
} 


Passenger lineToStruct(char line[])
{ 

    Passenger passengerL; 

    int classInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');

    char class = line[classInd+1];

    switch (class)
    {

        case 'f':
            strcpy(passengerL.class, "first");          
            break;      
        case 's':
            strcpy(passengerL.class, "second");
            break;      
        case 't':
            strcpy(passengerL.class, "third");
            break;          
        case 'c':
            strcpy(passengerL.class, "crew");
            break;      
        case 'a':
            strcpy(passengerL.class, "any");
            break;      
    }

    line[classInd] = '!';   


    int ageInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');
    char age = line[ageInd+2];

    switch (age)
    {
        case 'd':
            strcpy(passengerL.age, "adult");
            break;                  
        case 'h':
            strcpy(passengerL.age, "child");
            break;              
        case 'n':
            strcpy(passengerL.age, "any");
            break;      
    }

    line[ageInd]= '!';

    int genderInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');

    char gender = line[genderInd+3];


    switch (gender)
    {
        case 'l':
            strcpy(passengerL.gender, "male");
            break;          
        case 'm':
            strcpy(passengerL.gender, "female");
            break;          
        case 'y':
            strcpy(passengerL.gender, "any");
            break;              

    }


    line[genderInd] = '!';

    int survivedInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');

    char survived = line[survivedInd+1];

    switch (survived)
    {
        case 'y':
            strcpy(passengerL.survived, "yes");
            break;          
        case 'n':
            strcpy(passengerL.survived, "no");
            break;              
    }

    line[classInd] = '=';   
    line[ageInd] = '=';
    line[genderInd] = '=';

    return passengerL;

} 


Passenger queryToStruct(char line[])
{ 

    Passenger passengerQ; 

    int classInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');
    char class = line[classInd+1];

    switch (class)
    {
        case 'f':
            strcpy(passengerQ.class, "first");
            break;              
        case 's':
            strcpy(passengerQ.class, "second");
            break;          
        case 't':
            strcpy(passengerQ.class, "third");
            break;          
        case 'c':
            strcpy(passengerQ.class, "crew");
            break;      
        case 'a':
            strcpy(passengerQ.class, "any");
            break;  

    }

    line[classInd]= '!';
    int ageInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');
    char age = line[ageInd+2];

    switch (age)
    {
        case 'd':
            strcpy(passengerQ.age, "adult");
            break;
        case 'h':
            strcpy(passengerQ.age, "child");
            break;      
        case 'n':
            strcpy(passengerQ.age, "any");
            break;

    }

line[ageInd] = '!';


    int genderInd = findMyChar(line, 99, 0, '=');
    char gender = line[genderInd+3];


    switch (gender)
    {
        case 'l':
            strcpy(passengerQ.gender, "male");
            break;              
        case 'm':
            strcpy(passengerQ.gender, "female");
            break;      
        case 'y':
            strcpy(passengerQ.gender, "any");
            break;

    }

    line[classInd] = '=';   
    line[ageInd] = '=';


    return passengerQ;

}

int cmpStruct(Passenger pa, Passenger Query) 
{
    if (strcmp(Query.class, "any") != 0 && strcmp(Query.class, pa.class) != 0)
        return 1;

    if (strcmp(Query.age, "any") != 0 && strcmp(Query.age, pa.age) != 0)
        return 1;

    if (strcmp(Query.gender, "any") != 0 && strcmp(Query.gender, pa.gender) != 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

int Computation(Passenger Query, Passenger allPassengers[])
{        
    int totalPassengers = 0;

    int survived = 0;  

    float percentage;

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<numlines;i++)
    { 
        if (cmpStruct(allPassengers[i],Query)==0)
        { 
            totalPassengers++;  

            if (strcmp(allPassengers[i].survived,"yes")==0)
            {  
                survived++; 
                if (cmpStruct(allPassengers[i],Query)==1)
                {
                    printf("error");
                    break;
                } 

            }

        } 

    }

    percentage = survived/totalPassengers*100; 
    printf("\nResults:\n"); 
    printf("\nClass = %s\nAge = %s\nGender = %s\n\n",Query.class,Query.age,Query.gender); 

    if (totalPassengers == 0)
    { 
        printf("There was an error within the query\n");
    } 
    else 
    { 
        printf("%.0f passengers are in the query (of 2201), %.0f of them survived\n",totalPassengers,survived); 
    } 

    if (totalPassengers != 0)
    { 
        printf("Chance of survival is %.1f%c\n",percentage,'%');
    }

}
```

[Text File](https://cse.msu.edu/~cse220/proj/Titanic.txt)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FWAv.png)

The goal of this program is to use the given text file (Titanic.txt) and print out the chance of survival for any given query. The query can be entered like:

> class=first,age=child,gender=male
>
> class=crew,age=adult,gender=female
>
> class=any,age=adult,gender=any
>
> all
>
> etc.

The possible classes are first, second, third, and crew, the possible ages are adult or child, and the possible genders are male and female.

So, the problem I am having is when I enter 'all' my program is not producing a result. This is depicted within the picture of the outputs I gave. I think the error is either within my for-loop I use within my main function or within the computation function I use at the end of my program.

Comment: "titanic.txt" and this wall of code ... . No one is going to read this. Please provide a [mcve] and ask a *specific** question. you might want to learn [ask].

Comment: And note that all requiered information has to be **in** the question text, not linked. But first you should strip down your code.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `#define linelen 99`  When defining a numeric value, always surround the value in parens so no 'text replacement' errors occur.  I.E. `#define linelen (99)`.    Now that that number has been given a meaningful name, use that name throughout the code, so lines like: `char class[99];` should be: `char class[linelen];`   Also, it is general practice to write #define names in all capitals with root words separated by underscores.  I.E. `#define LINE_LEN (99)`  Then use 'LINE_LEN' everywhere that '99' is currently being used

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile and some of the warnings are serious enough to cause seg fault events.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then fix those warnings.  Please fix the warnings then post the new code as an new text code segment.

Comment: the '=' assignment operator for a non C intrinsic variable (like a struct), other than when the left operand is first being created will usually be a very bad idea and probably will not work as expected.  There are several places in the code that exhibit this kind of problem.  So this function: `Passenger lineToStruct(char line[])` will probably not work as expected.  Suggest 1) inside the function, malloc the needed area 2) return a pointer to that malloc'd area,  3) Let the caller copy the data to the local array, then pass that pointer to `free()`.

Comment: this line: `Passenger allPassengers[numlines];` is allocating a 2201 byte array, but the line: `if (fgets(line, linelen, fp) == NULL)` is only using the first 99 bytes.  Also, this expression: `fgets(line, linelen, fp)` should be the controlling statement/expression inside the `while( expression )` rather than `while(1)`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. A group and I were just looking to get a project just working and small details like issue you pointed out with array lengths of [99] were being ignored until we could flesh out a working program. Sorry for all the mistakes though! My group are all greatly inexperienced with coding so much of this is still confusing and/or unfamiliar to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main problem**

```
if(query == "all")
```

is wrong. It compares two pointers. It does not compare the strings. You need to use:

```
if( strcmp(query, "all") == 0 )
```

**Other errors**

I get the following messages from gcc when compiling with `-Wall` flag.

```
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:83:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[99]’ [-Wformat=]
          scanf("%s", &query);  
          ^
soc.c:91:16: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
       if(query == "all")
                ^
soc.c: In function ‘Computation’:
soc.c:439:7: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
       printf("%.0f passengers are in the query (of 2201), %.0f of them survived\n",totalPassengers,survived); 
       ^
soc.c:439:7: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
soc.c:447:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

The first one can be fixed by changing

```
scanf("%s", &query);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", query);  
            ^^^ Remove the &
```

The second one is the main problem.

The third one can be fixed by using `%d` instead of `%.0f` in the format string.

The fourth one can be fixed by changing the return type of `Computation` to `void`. Since you are not returning anything from the function and the place where it is called does not expect a return value, changing the return type to `void` seems to make sense.

There is one more error that was not caught by the compiler. It is the following line:

```
percentage = survived/totalPassengers*100;
```

This will result in `0` being assigned to `percentage` due to integer division. Change it to:

```
percentage = 1.0*survived/totalPassengers*100;
```

or

```
percentage = 100.0*survived/totalPassengers;
```

Comment: THANK YOU. You have no idea how much this means to me (and my group).

Comment: This fixed it!!! Thank you so much, again.